Allowing Multiple Submissions of the Same Form and Viewing Previous and New Entries
I need help with a CRM form. I want the form to be filled out multiple times by an admin. For example, if an admin submits the form, they should be able to come back later and add more entries. The previous and new details should be displayed, possibly in an accordion format, allowing the admin to view both the old and new entries. How can I achieve this functionality?


Have you tried using Activity?

How can activity help with this? Could you explain in more detail how we can achieve this with a form builder?
